# Error when paying on Opencart,how to fix?

Tags: php

I have the same error. When paying for goods on OpenCart v3.*.*.*
The script cannot check the payment and whether it has arrived at all.
although money is withdrawn
I checked the logs and found this error

> [20-Sep-2023 11:28:08 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Error: MySQL server has gone away
> Error No: 2006
> SELECT *, (SELECT os.name FROM `oc_order_status` os WHERE os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id AND os.language_id = o.language_id) AS order_status FROM `oc_order` o WHERE o.order_id = '488' in /home/t9v8phnxnf9s/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php:48
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /home/t9v8phnxnf9s/public_html/system/library/db.php(45): DB\MySQLi->query('SELECT *, (SELE...')
>
> #1 /home/t9v8phnxnf9s/public_html/catalog/model/checkout/order.php(125): DB->query('SELECT *, (SELE...')
>
> #2 /home/t9v8phnxnf9s/public_html/catalog/model/checkout/order.php(272): ModelCheckoutOrder->getOrder(488)
>
> #3 /home/t9v8phnxnf9s/storage/modification/system/engine/loader.php(248): ModelCheckoutOrder->addOrderHistory(488, '1', 'PayPal Seller P...')
>
> #4 /home/t9v8phnxnf9s/public_html/system/engine/proxy.php(47): Loader->{closure}(Array, Array)
>
> #5 /home/t9v8phnxnf9s/public_html/catalog/controller/extension/payment/paypal.php(448): Proxy->__call('addOrderHistory', Arra in /home/t9v8phnxnf9s/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 48

I tried to register it in config.php
these commands but nothing helped:

And this problem is connected not only with PayPal but also with DebitCard

```
# MySQL timeout settings
wait_timeout = 90
net_read_timeout = 90
net_write_timeout = 90
interactive_timeout = 300
connect_timeout = 90

# MySQL max_allowed_packet
max_allowed_packet = 512M
```

If anyone knows what can be done about this, you can help.
I've been trying to solve the problem for days now.
Moreover, if I send the same request manually it works

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html - have you investigated all the possible reasons listed here

Comment: I just don’t know what to try, any ideas?

Comment: Yes, the ideas are in that link